# Perform periodic task using BASH and watch command

Tags: scripting, git, watch

I'm trying to write a BASH script with the purpose of using `watch` command to monitor a local git repository for changes from the remote branch and then executing a task.

Let's say the script is called `task.sh` and looks like:

```
watch -n 3000 (git remote update && git status) | \
grep -i "your branch is behind origin/" && \ 
{ "pull changes, run tests, etc." ; }
```

What I have posted is more or less what I have thus far, but I can't seem to get the last part to work. In other words, it doesn't seem to pick up when I have a made a change to the git branch. I was able to redirect the output from `watch` to a file like this `watch -n 3000 ls 1>> file.txt` , but using this method would require opening the file which I think is slow and error prone.

I basically want `watch` to continuously run until I kill the script that started it, although if there's a better method than `watch` that would be fine too.

Comment: Uh..  `cron` looks like a much better foreman for this particular job.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I was hoping that my script would be simpler and would give me a little more control but that hasn't been the case.

Answer (score 1):

As DopeGhoti mentioned, `cron` would be a much better choice for this.

Your example already has a 50 minute interval. If making the interval an hour is acceptable, many modern distros have an `/etc/cron.hourly` directory. Anything in that directory with the executable bit set will be run hourly (most implementations I've seen use `run-parts` which runs the executables in that directory linearly by filename).

If a shorter interval is a must, I'd recommend `/etc/cron.d`. The cron daemon generally parses this directory directly, so there is no need for the executable bit to be set. You could create a file called `task` with the following contents.

```
*/30 * * * * root /path/to/task.sh
```

The first 5 fields are for minute, hour, day of the month, month, and day of the week. In this case we're giving minute a step value of 30 minutes. So, this particular example will run `task.sh` every 30 minutes, every hour, every day of the month, every... you get the idea.

Step values over 30 minutes in the minutes field lead to execution at `N` minutes past the hour, where `N` is the value in the minutes field.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181949/how-do-set-cron-to-run-my-script-every-40mins-25mins) for one solution to odd intervals.

Now on to the bash code...

The reason this isn't working as expected is because `grep` never returns an exit value to be evaluated by `&&`. It's still `grep`ing the output of `watch`.

This can be seen in the following example. The `echo` and `sleep` within the curly braces take the place of `watch`. After the `sleep` exits, `grep` can too. The second date doesn't run until after `grep` exits and the exit code can be evaluated.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ date +%s; { echo a; sleep 15; } | grep 'a' && date +%s
1493875975
a
1493875990
```

One way to correct this would be to move everything to be within `watch`.

```
watch -n 15 'bash -c "echo a | grep 'a' && date +%s"'
```

Another option is use a while-true-loop.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ while :; do echo a | grep 'a' && date +%s; sleep 15; done
a
1493875992
a
1493876007
a
1493876022
^C
```